# Promise Technology VTrak configure webserver

Tags: admin

I inherited management of some Promise VTrak disk array servers. They recently had to be transferred to a different location. We've got them set up and networking is all configured, and even have a linux server mounting to it. Before they were transferred I was trained with the web gui it comes with. However, since the move we have not been able to connect to the web gui interface.

I can ssh into the system and really do everything from there, but I would love to figure out why webserver is not coming up.

The VTRAK system does not allow for much configuration it seams. From the CLI I can start, stop, or restart the webserver, and the only thing I can configure is the amount of time someone can be logged into the gui for. I don't see anywhere where you can configure http or anything like that.

We're pretty sure it's not a firewall issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue this morning, and resolved it as follows:

It appears there are conditions that can render the WebPam webserver with invalid configuration HttpPort and HttpsPort values. One condition that causes this is if the sessiontimeout parameter exceeds 1439 set in the GUI. Apparently the software then freaks and creates invalid configuration which locks out the GUI because the http ports have been changed to 25943 and 29538.

To fix this login through CLI:

```
swmgt -a mod -n webserver -s "sessiontimeout=29"
swmgt -a mod -n webserver -s "HttpPort=80"  
swmgt -a mod -n webserver -s "HttpsPort=443"   
swmgt -a restart -n Webserver
```

You should now be able to access the WebPam webserver interface again through your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with my IT department we found it was a firewall issue.